# Can I abandon a quest and get it back in Dungeons of dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I have spent hours on 2 empty floor(s). On occasion I find items I did not have room to pickup. But no sign of my quest item or monsters. Can I abandon the quest and reacquire it to reset the quest or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've abandoned a quest from a statue, you cannot get another quest from the statue. That means you can't reacquire the quest once you abandon it, unfortunately.

Source: [Dredmor Wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Statue_of_Inconsequentia)

Comment: It has happened several times to me that I couldn't find a quest item/enemy while playing with "No time to grind". Does anyone know if that's a known bug?

Comment: @Bruce: I can't find any reports of it on the Dredmor bugs forum after a quick look, so its possible that they don't know about it yet. That forum is here: http://community.gaslampgames.com/forums/bugs.6/

Comment: @BruceConnor - They're now working on fixing that problem in the next patch, and there's also a test exe you can download that might fix it right now - http://www.gaslampgames.com/2011/12/28/post-holiday-update/